# Does Terraria for Android need an internet connection to run?

Tags: android, terraria-mobile

I have big technical problems with buying things over internet, but when I discovered new Terraria version for Android has been released I was really excited. I really like the game and I decided to figure out how to buy it.

As I was reading the comments I begun to have a strong suspicion that the game needs internet to run because it checks for user license.

[image]

I contacted Terraria's developers through a form on their site, but the request was ignored, so I decided to ask fellow Terraria players here.

Does Terraria Mobile require an internet connection to run?

Comment: Why is there no explanation for the 2 downvotes?

Comment: Where are you reading that this game needs an internet connection to run? I've gone through several forum boards, and checked several pages of comments on the Google Play Store. AFAIK Terraria mobile has not, and will not require a persistent online connection.

Comment: Some comments (czech) said things like "*sometimes doesn't start... probably needs internet to start...*". Since the demo version does some obvious connection at start, I think my question is quite legit. I still want the votes on my question explained.

Answer (score 1):

Terraria 1.1.6292 on my Android runs normally when my phone is in airplane mode.

Comment: But 1.1.6 is not what's being currently sold. Does your version contain hardmode, rails and other new content?